# How to linearly combine a list of lists in python, where not every item is a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list composed of strings and lists:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', ['fgh', 'rst'], 'i',['quv','wxy']]
```

How do I join each element in this list so that all of the string elements contain one of each internal list element, while maintaining their position in the original list? Ex:

```
targets = ['abcdefghiquv',
           'abcdefghiwxy',
           'abcderstiquv',
           'abcderstiwxy',
          ]
```

I have attempted it in the manner below, but, this only works if the last element is a list

```
combinations = []
combinations2 = []
for s in a:
    if isinstance(s, basestring):
        combinations.append(s)
    else:
        seqint = ''.join(combinations)
        combinations2.append([seqint])
        combinations2.append(s)
        combinations[:]=[]
for comb in list(itertools.product(*combinations2)):
    print ''.join(comb)
```

Comment: What have you tried already to attempt to solve this? Can you show your code and explain what difficulties you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `itertools.product` is surely the way to go. I would do it this way (may not be totally correct since I have never used legacy Python much):

```
# helper function
def strtolist(o):
    '''Takes an object and puts it in a list if it's a string'''
    if isinstance(o, str):
        return [o]
    return o

a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', ['fgh', 'rst'], 'i',['quv','wxy']]
newa = [strtolist(item) for item in a]
```

That last step is called a list comprehension. They are very useful, so it would be a good use of time to go read about them (there are also dictionary comprehensions and generator comprehensions).

Now we have a new list that looks like this:

```
newa = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['fgh', 'rst'], ['i'],['quv','wxy']]
```

Then finish up the same as you did before:

```
from itertools import product

for comb in list(product(*newa)):
    print ''.join(comb)
```

EDIT: if you really want to get gnarly, you can do all of that in a single statement. But I don't recommend it (not very readable):

```
>>> result = [''.join(combo) for combo in product(*[([item] if isinstance(item, basestr) else item) for item in a])]
>>> assert result == targets
# no error: success
```

It seems like you are in the process of learning so I'll make an additional comment: unless you have a really good reason for learning using legacy Python (2), I would suggest switching to modern Python (current version 3.6). It is the direction everything is headed at this point (though legacy Python will probably still be around for quite a while in many contexts).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach by getting the list indices and using itertools.product

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', ['fgh', 'rst'], 'i',['quv','wxy'] ]
idx = []
lst = []
for i in a:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        idx.append(a.index(i))
        lst.append(i)

from itertools import product

for j in [ dict( zip(idx,i) ) for i in product(*lst) ] :
    for k,v in j.items():
        a[k] = v
    print ( ''.join(a) )
```

Answer (score 0):

As a functional style you can `reduce` the list:

```
list(reduce(lambda x, y: (x1 + "".join(y1) for x1 in x for y1 in y), a))
['abcdefghiquv', 'abcdefghiwxy', 'abcderstiquv', 'abcderstiwxy']
```